# Regex pattern for an expression

Tags: regex

I need to count the number of multiple groups that are mentioned in Excel cells. There are multiple groups name in on cell, all of them following a certain pattern. The group names are polluted by other words. Each group name is on one line in one cell.

While I was able to figure out the way to use VBA to create a function in order to count, I am still struggling with the Regex pattern and for this reason the final number sometimes includes non-groups or by contrary is not including groups.

```
Pattern = "(?=.*\d)[^\n " & Chr(34) & "]+"
```

Here is the pattern for the group names:

3 capital letters
Dot
2 numbers
Dot
4 capital letters
Dot
4 capital letters or 3 capital letters and 1 number
Dot
Anything of any length and any combination (letters, dots, numbers no spaces, capital or lower, underscores, dashes)
Each groups is on a new line
Non groups could start with a capital letter or lower letter but for sure they are not capital letters for the whole name and MUST be eliminated

Example (all the bellow lines are found in a single cell in Excel)

Initial setup

```
Please write
GTU.10.GENG.GENG.Cloudera_Admin
PRD.12.BFEN.SIDD.WD12LBE0550.Administrator
TST.16.SYWF.GEET.EU.R-Softw.10
Nested in
TST.10.SYWF.GEI1.AS.R
please rename
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.W
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.R
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.W-ExclusionList
```

Expected result

```
GTU.10.GENG.GENG.Cloudera_Admin
PRD.12.BFEN.SIDD.WD12LBE0550.Administrator
TST.16.SYWF.GEET.EU.R-Softw.10
TST.10.SYWF.GEI1.AS.R
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.W
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.R
PRD.16.SYWF.AGIW.AS.W-ExclusionList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
[A-Z]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[A-Z]{4}\.[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9].*
```

See on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nCkgv1/1).

Comment: I think the OP needs to remove mismatched parts of input, not find mathng parts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the regex from [Zipa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5811078/zipa) above, this is a full example of a custom function returning what the OP asked for

```
'Use the Tools|References command in the VBA Editor to reference the library
'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

```vb
Public Function strFilter(SubjectString)
    Dim myMatch As Match
    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp
    Dim retString As String, bNewLine As Boolean
    ' initialise variables
    bNewLine = False
    retString = ""
    ' configure regex
    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.Pattern = "[A-Z]{3}\.[0-9]{2}\.[A-Z]{4}\.[A-Z]{3}[A-Z0-9].*"
    ' this is needed for iterating over all matches
    myRegExp.Global = True
    ' execute RegEx match
    Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(SubjectString)
    For Each myMatch In myMatches
        If (bNewLine) Then
            ' not first match -> add newline now
            retString = retString & vbNewLine
        Else
            ' 1st match, no new line needed yet, but next match will require one
            bNewLine = True
        End If
        ' concat matches
        retString = retString & myMatch.Value
    Next
    'return filtered expression
    strFilter = retString
End Function
```